# Hamiltonian cycles in balanced bipartite graph - proof of theorem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm, hamiltonian-path, bipartite-graphs

does anyone have an idea how to proof this theorem?

Let $B$ be a balanced bipartite graph of order $2n$, $n ≥ 2$, as defined
below and $s, t$ be two integers in $[0, n − 1]$. Then $D_s ∪ D_t$
forms a Hamilton cycle in
$B$ if $\gcd(|t − s|, n) = 1$.

And needed theory:
Balanced bipartite graph $B = (X ∪ Y, E)$ with vertex set $V = X ∪ Y$ ,
where $|X| = |Y|$, $X = {x_1, x_2, · · · , x_n}$ and $Y = {y_1, y_2, · · · , y_n}$. For
$0 ≤ i ≤ n−1$, define $Di = \{x_jy_k : i ≡ j − k \pmod n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a proposition of elementary number theory more than graph theory.  I might mess up the signs of the indices a little, but this is the idea behind your argument.

Imagine the cycle of the graph that includes $y_1$.  $y_1$ is adjacent via $D_t$ to $x_{t+1}$.  It's other neighbor (via $D_s$) is $y_{t-s+1}$.  The vertex in $Y$ that comes next is $y_{2(t-s)+1}$, and so on.  If (and only if) $\gcd(t-s,n)=1$, then this sequence of vertices in $Y$ will hit all of the vertices of $Y$ before returning to $y_1$, leaving you with a Hamilton cycle.  The cycle also hits all the vertices in $X$ by symmetry, since $X$ and $Y$ are balanced.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But I am not really convinced that $x_1$ is adjacent to $y_{t+1}$ cause applying indexes to the definition of $D_t$ we get: $-t \equiv 1-(t+1) \pmod n$. So it seems like $x_1$ is connected to $y_{n-t+1}$ and so on? Correct me if I'm wrong. But I got the idea of the proof so thank you again.

Comment: @angelene Yup, that was the "I might mess up the indices" comment.  Working from the $y$'s might make the indices work out the prettier way that I planned out.  As Tom Lehrer once said when getting his sums wrong in public, the idea is the important thing. ^_^

Comment: Edited to flip over to considering the vertices of $Y$ in the cycle.

Comment: Alright it's all clear now. It's actually easy i don't know why I had problems with this. Thank you!